# Display unique values on flask jinja template

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I have a query on my views.py:

`query = db.session.query(Basket, Fruits).filter(Fruits.basket_id == Basket.id)`

In the html template, I wish to display for each basket id (basket id here is unique), what are the fruits inside each basket, thus I used a nested for loop in my template.

I have tried on the html template:

```
{% for basket in query | unique %}
<p>{{ basket.Basket.id }}</p>
{% for fruits in query %}
<p>{% if basket.Basket.id == fruits.Basket.id %}
<p>{{ query.Fruits.fruit }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But the unique basket id is not displayed.

I have thought of creating 2 queries so that I can put .distinct and display the unique basket id, then use the other query to display the fruits, but that didn't make sense to me because I still need all the information in the whole query. Beginner in flask btw.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve that with a [one to many relationship](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#one-to-many-relationships).

```
class Basket(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    fruits = db.relationship('Fruit', backref='basket')

class Fruit(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    basket_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('basket.id'))


@app.route('/')
def baskets():
    baskets = db.session.query(Basket).all()
    return render_template('baskets.html', baskets=baskets )
```

Jinja2 Template:

```
{% for b in baskets %}
<ul>
  <p>
    {% b.name %}
  </p>
  {% for f in b.fruits %}
    <li>{{ f.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```